# Formatting dynamic text element in Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

Is there a way to format the Name element generated as dynamic text from [Data Driven Pages](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisdesktop/archive/2010/01/22/Data-Driven-Pages.aspx)?

This element serves as my title and it is too long and needs to be wrapped onto another line.

Comment: I was wondering if you can add a bit more detail to what you're trying to do

Comment: I think there may be a valuable Question that is being asked here but would like to see more details edited into it so that we can get an Accept-able Answer to it.

Answer (score 3):

Type the following for the text: Coordinate System:

```
<dyn type="dataFrame" name="Detail Map" property="sr" srProperty="name"/ dyn   
type="dataFrame" name="Detail Map" property="sr" srProperty="projection"  
preStr="Projection: " newLine="true" emptyStr=""/ dyn type="dataFrame"   
name="Detail Map" property="sr" srProperty="datum" preStr="Datum: "     
newLine="true" emptyStr=""/ dyn type="dataFrame" name="Detail Map"   
property="sr" srProperty="units" preStr="Units: " newLine="true" emptyStr=""/>
```

I think this is an example of using a newline=true in the middle of a dynamic text string.

Answer (score 2):

If your title is not already a [ParagraphTextElement](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ParagraphTextElementClass_Class/001200000s67000000/), you might try converting it into one.  Seems like there should be a way to do this interactively in arcmap, but I don't see one.

Comment: I broke the "too-long" title down into several new columns.  Then I made multiple dynamic text references to several of the column names in my DDP table.  Then I combined static and dynamic text together.  Otherwise, you're left with basic tag formating of the text.

Comment: @Taj - Go ahead and post this as an answer to your own question.  The community can vote for which approach is the best.

Answer (score 2):

What is not well documented is the fact that Dynamic Text in data driven pages can pull any of the information from the table you are running the data driven pages off (the index layer).

Simply use `<dyn type="page" property="SHAPE_Area"/>` where SHAPE_Area can be replaced by any column in the table.